# Missing Elements from HTML File Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to the web-scraping world, and I'm trying to scrape the names of shoes from a website. When I use inspect on the website, there's a div tag that has basically the entire webpage inside it, but when I print out the html code, the div tag is completely empty! Here's my current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

def findShoeNames():
   html_file = requests.get('https://www.goat.com/sneakers/brand/air-jordan').text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'lxml')
   print(soup)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
   findShoeNames()
```

When I call my function and print(soup), the div tag looks like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

But as previously mentioned, when I hit inspect on the website, this div tag has basically the entire webpage inside it. So I'm unable to scrape any data from the website.

Please help! Thanks

Comment: What’s the URL? The page is probably loaded dynamically

Comment: https://www.goat.com/sneakers/brand/air-jordan - Does that mean I'd need to use selenium? @MendelG

Comment: Data comes from API POST request to `https://2fwotdvm2o-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(3.35.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.2.2)%3B%20react%20(16.13.1)%3B%20react-instantsearch%20(6.8.2)&x-algolia-application-id=2FWOTDVM2O&x-algolia-api-key=ac96de6fef0e02bb95d433d8d5c7038a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

website use js to load. so you should use selenium and chromedriver.
install selenium
install chromedriver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.42/) (unzip and copy your python folder)

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.goat.com/sneakers/brand/air-jordan"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(1)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify)
```

Comment: I get the following error when using your code: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: it's because chromedriver is not in python path.

Comment: for win usually appdata/local/Programs/Python/Python39

Comment: Got it! Thanks!!